# Migrate models in package hierachy without South

Tags: django, django-1.8

I'm on Django 1.8. Rather than all my models being in a single `models.py` file, I have them in a package that looks like this:

```
models/
  - __init__.py
  - Album.py
  - Artist.py
```

But Django's `makemigrations` command appears to work only when an app has a single `models.py` file. Running `django-admin help makemigrations` does not bring up any hints on additional options that I can pass to the command to achieve what I want. Also, all other questions and answers I've seen here on SO involve South, which is incompatible with Django 1.8.

So what's the workaround?

Comment: First question, why do want to do that?

Comment: For code maintainability, of course. It's preferable that each model live in its own file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontally splitting django models across multiple files is a valid approach. A good explanation can be found [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookSplitModelsToFiles).

Django looks for your models in the `models` module which can be a file or a valid python package.

If you have a valid python package( a directory with a `__init__.py` file) it will try to discover the models based on the contents of `__init__.py`.

Make sure that your `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from Album import Album
from Artist import Artist
```

Then django should discover your models correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py`

add.

```
 # myproject/app/models.py:
 from models/Album.py import *
 from models/Artist.py import *
```

Note about [django-south](/questions/tagged/django-south): From [django-1.7](/questions/tagged/django-1.7) migrations has been started supported. Please check [Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/).

Comment: You may want to check out the answer given by Sebastian above. His method works but thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: His answer pretty correct but this is also answer as a another way to do it.

Comment: No. His answer is the **right** way to do it and you shouldn't have marked my question as a duplicate. That other question is 3 years old, is about Django 1.3, and its answer is nowhere near as slick as the answer that I've accepted today.